# Is it possible to delete broken revisions from jsperf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile, jsperf

I'm doing my first steps with `jsperf` ([here](http://jsperf.com)) to improve the performance of some of my scripts.

I'm wondering if it is possible to delete/remove test revisions, which I have accidentially published - they are broken and unusable, so:

**Question:**
Say I figured out how it works when doing revision 5 - is there a way to delete revision 1-4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I’m the guy who created jsPerf.

There is no way to delete test cases on jsPerf other than emailing me or asking @jsperf on Twitter nicely. This is by design.

How do you end up with 4 broken revisions, though? Whenever you edit a test case that you created within the same browser session, it will simply update the original test case.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should read some [instructions](http://www.slideshare.net/mathiasbynens/using-jsperf-correctly) but I just started playing around - anyway, I finished my first working test and this seems to be the only one published, so I'm good. Thanks for the information tough :-)

Comment: Why by design? Does it make (site/app) code simpler? or is it another reason? btw, i (recently) have various test cases which i update (and depending on time of development) after a couple of days, but they are prototypes. it would be better to have a couple of definitive tests than a plethora of revisions (sometimes up to 50) and other users dont know which one is the main test involved

Comment: One reason might be because the form is not great and often says something like, "not all test cases added" and really it means there aren't *any* test cases.